# Pylance complains no parameter named "response" in flask app.response_class

Tags: flask, pylance

It appears the flask source code has used the alias "Response" for multiple different types. "Go to Definition" for `app.response_class` takes me to `flask > sansio > app.py > App > response_class`. In this module we have `from werkzeug.sansio.response import Response`.

Pylance seems mistaken. What `app.response_class` *really* points to is `flask > wrappers.py > Response`, where we have `from werkzeug.wrappers import Response as ResponseBase` (Response inherits from ResponseBase). This is confirmed by...

1. [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.response_class) points to the latter.
2. My code works with the allegedly nonexistent kwarg.

Currently I'm fixing this with a [`# type:ignore`](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/929#issuecomment-775614787) on the offending line, but I wish Pylance were smarter. Is there something I'm missing, or a better workaround here?